# Broken dependencies on CentOS 6.4: can install nodejs but not npm

Tags: centos, yum, node.js, epel, centos6.4

I'm using a fresh installed CentOS 6.4 (x86-64) with the EPEL repository.

```
$ yum install nodejs
...
$ node -v
v0.10.5
```

So far, so good, but when I try to install `npm`, I'll get this error message:

```
$ yum install npm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * extras: centos.psw.net
 * updates: centos.psw.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package npm.noarch 0:1.2.17-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: npm(which) < 2 for package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: npm(uid-number) < 1 for package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: npm(tar) < 0.2 for package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: npm(slide) < 2 for package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: npm(semver) < 1.2 for package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch
...
(skipped)
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nodejs-npmlog-0.0.2-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(ansi) < 0.2
Error: Package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(ansi) < 0.2
Error: Package: nodejs-npmlog-0.0.2-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(ansi) >= 0.1.2
Error: Package: npm-1.2.17-5.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: npm(ansi) >= 0.1.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The complete output is quite big:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ce3ZJsEB

What should I do? The `--skip-broken` workaround doesn't seem to be right solution.

Here is the output of `yum repolist`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.copahost.com
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * extras: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: centos.copahost.com
 repo id       repo name                                            status
 base          CentOS-6 - Base                                      6,381
 epel          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64       8,909
 extras        CentOS-6 - Extras                                       12
 updates       CentOS-6 - Updates                                     727
 repolist: 16,029
```

Comment: what is your 'yum repolist'?

Comment: @AndreiMikhaltsov I added the output of `yum repolist`

Comment: I think you skipped the part we need to see: `--> Processing Dependency: npm(ansi) ...`

Comment: @AaronCopley I ran the command again. The output is availabe here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ce3ZJsEB (I also edited my post to insert the link.)

Comment: What happens when you install `nodejs-ansi` first? `yum install nodejs-ansi`

Comment: Nevermind ... There was a lot more to it than I thought. :)

Comment: I ended up installing by source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package **nodejs-ansi** from EPEL (*nodejs-ansi-0.1.2-7.el6.noarch*) is broken.

Try:

```
wget http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/nodejs-ansi/0.1.2/7.el6.1/noarch/nodejs-ansi-0.1.2-7.el6.1.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo="epel" install npm ./nodejs-ansi-0.1.2-7.el6.1.noarch.rpm
```

Solution founded on #epel at irc.freenode.net.

See also: http://pastebin.com/mqFqRqUp
line 28

Comment: Solved my problem. But minor typo on "eneblerepo" vs "enablerepo".