# yum update fails to unpack archives for nodejs dependencies on centos 6.4

Tags: yum, centos6, node.js

I run "yum update" on my CentOS 6.4, but the Node.js package and dependencies fail with multiple errors like this:

```
Error unpacking rpm package nodejs-fstream-0.1.23-1.el6.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs: cpio: rename
```

...
and so on for every package. Full output here http://pastebin.com/g8AprsNG

The package list is this (all from epel):

- node-gyp | 0.10.6-1.el6
- nodejs-boom | 0.4.2-2.el6
- nodejs-fstream | 0.1.23-1.el6
- nodejs-fstream-ignore | 0.0.7-1.el6
- nodejs-fstream-npm | 0.1.5-1.el6
- nodejs-glob | 3.2.3-1.el6
- nodejs-hawk | 0.15.0-1.el6
- nodejs-init-package-json | 0.0.10-1.el6
- nodejs-npm-registry-client | 0.2.27-1.el6
- nodejs-npmconf | 0.1.1-1.el6
- nodejs-npmlog | 0.0.4-1.el6
- nodejs-read-installed | 0.2.2-1.el6
- nodejs-read-package-json | 1.1.0-2.el6
- nodejs-request | 2.21.0-1.el6
- nodejs-sntp | 0.2.4-1.el6
- npm | 1.3.3-1.el6

There was no problem with the updates before.

I have read the answer on this question [Broken dependencies on CentOS 6.4: can install nodejs but not npm](https://serverfault.com/questions/511997/broken-dependencies-on-centos-6-4-can-install-nodejs-but-not-npm) but I have nodejs-ansi at version 0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Solved eventually by removing node completely and re-installing it from source.